# How can I include the the original Item ID# in a new Item created/cloned using Power Automate flow?

Tags: calculated-column, flow, clone

I am using Power Automate to clone original Items in an existing SharePoint List.  All is working perfectly, as the clone flow results in an exact copy of the original List Item.  Now my users want to include the original Item ID number as a Reference in the new, cloned Item.  I am struggling how to accomplish this requirement.  I tried using a calculated column (Ref_ID = [ID], but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't set directly set a the value of a calculated column. I suggest you use a text or number column instead.

**Additional information to address comment:**

You are copying (cloning) items from a source list to a target list. The two lists will have the same fields (columns), except that the target list will have one additional column to store the item Id of the source item. I suggest this column be a text or number column.

When you do the copy (clone), you copy the field (column) values from the source item to the target item including the source item's Id to the additional column in the target item.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your Answer. Did you intend to say: "I'm pretty sure you can't *[clone]* the value of a calculated column..." So how can I make reference to the Item ID for the original Item in the new, cloned Item? What do you mean "use a text or number column instead"? Please expand on you answer... Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: @Al_R I expanded on my answer. Hopefully this will clear up any confusion.